# Fill Mysql table with information from excel sheet including relative path to images

Tags: java, php, python, mysql

Here is the task I am trying to accomplish:

I have an excel sheet with product information ( reference, description, price, quantity available and image). I would like to use this excel sheet to fill a database(Mysql), which will be used to retrieve information for a product search engine. I am expecting a large number of products ( ~ 1,500), which is the reason why I do not want to upload items manually. What would be the best approach to do this? My main concern is the images. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Where does your difficulty lies exactly?

If it's in reading an excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'yourfile.xlsx')
```

If it's in connecting and inserting values into MySQL:

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect( host="localhost", user="root", passwd="" )
curs = db.cursor()
curs.execute("INSERT INTO <> VALUES ( , , )")
```

If it's in linking the two, please describe your difficulties

Comment: The problem I am currently experiencing is reading the images. I am now able to fill my database with the excel sheet information, however, I am unsure on how to upload the images as well so I can later reference them

Comment: How are your images embedded in the excel? Is that an URL, a base64 encoding? Could you provide some example of what the excel looks like maybe?